# whose view is not in the window hierarchy! issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard, segue

My project was first created with a UITabBarController as the first view to appear, then I needed to add a custom splash screen that appears for 3 sec so I used a new UIViewController which appears before the UITabBarController and I set this custom splash screen as the first view to appear. However, after I did that change. At the moment my splash screen goes to the UITabBarController im receiving this error.

Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController: 0x1cdcfe30 on SplashViewController: 0x1cdc55e0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Im performing the change of view in my SplashViewController in this way:

```
#import "SplashViewController.h"

@interface SplashViewController ()

@end

@implementation SplashViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)changeView{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splash" sender:self];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

By the way im using storyboards this is a strange error that appears in the console all the time after I added that splash screen and I cant figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: Posting some code would make your problem clearer and easy to solve.

Comment: I update it now... but basically thats all what I have in the .m

Comment: ok and after i perform that change of view just loads the UITabBarController... I think that somehow the storyboard is configured to launch initially the UITabBarController, because when I created the project Ive choosen create Tabbed application

Comment: There should be an arrow pointing to the view controller that is initially launched when the app loads on your storyboard. If it is pointing to your tab bar controller, you might try dragging it to your splash screen instead.

Comment: Yes its pointing to the view controller...When this arrow points this view controller I get the error and when it points to the TabBarController everything goes fine. But I need this splash screen so I cant get rid of it...

Answer (score 1):

Give Storyboard id "TabBarViewController" for TabBarController in Identity Inspector(Storyboard)

And implement changeView as-

```
-(void)changeView
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    TabBarViewController *tabBarViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarViewController"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:tabBarViewController];
}
```

Comment: I used your code and it worked... But now the app starts to run slowly when I press the tabs and then it just freezes... By the way, the error dissappeared.

Comment: Been looking for that for hours!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add another controller for a splash screen. Just add a view (your splash screen view) on top of the view of the controller in the first tab. That view will appear at app start up, then after whatever delay you want, fade out that view and remove it from its superview.

Comment: Wish I had read this before creating my app lol. Lesson lernt